How many degrees of freedom in a T-copula is commonly used to model financial data?
I'm looking to fit some T-copulas to my financial return data. Unfortunately, the software I'm using can only fit a T-copula with a fixed degree of freedom parameter.
So what parameter should I use? What is commonly used for financial return data?
I have zero intuition here. I know that infinity gives me the normal distribution, so that's probably not it. But should it be 1? 2? 3? 4? 5? 6? 7? I have no clue.

How much tail-dependence do you want?

The smallest value for the degree of freedom for t-copula must be 2. Also, you may try different models and select the model that best fits your data.
